# Tag-Cleanup: Process

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request, ambiguous-tags

The [process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/process) is most used to describe OS processes. However, some questions tagged process relate to software engineering process models and methodologies and some others are "how to do X" questions (such as "Benefits of stripping trailing whitespace?". In a perfect world, these software engineering process questions would be [somewhere else (shameless plug)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6922/software-engineering), but that place doesn't exist yet. In the mean time, the process tag should be removed from every post where it does not refer to a system process.

It looks like the only way to do this is to manually go through everything tagged process...

EDIT: Just wondering if anyone else had any feedback before I jumped in and started retagging everything tagged [process]. Retagging will affect nearly 1300 questions, so we better be sure of what we want to do before we do it.

Comment: i agree, it is ambiguous

Comment: It's not ambiguous. In the context of Stack Overflow, "process" should refer to instances of running applications and not methodologies. It's just that the same term is used in other areas that are somewhat related to the content of Stack Overflow to mean different things.

Comment: You just described ambiguous, my friend ;)

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Feedback for before you do the huge job? I suggest you look at the advice I got over at [this etiquette question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52816/etiquette-for-enormous-hand-sorted-retagging-jobs).

Answer (score 1):

`[process]` is ambiguous. All instances should be changed to non-ambiguous alternatives such as `[system-process]` or `[process-model]` unless the question has nothing to do with processes of any kind, in which case the tag should be removed from that question.

The tag cleanup process will have to be performed manually.

Comment: Well, I don't have any big plans tomorrow...I suppose I'll start it off, then.